# How can I dynamically extend arguments of a method?

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper

The methods should be callable by assigning the specific parameters as well as considering the class' attributes.

So what I like to achieve is overwriting a method's arguments with preset attributes.

E.g.:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, cfg=None):
        self.cfg = {}
        if cfg:
            self.cfg = cfg
        return
    
    def _actual_f_1(self, x, **kwargs):
        return x+100
    
    def f_1(self, x):
        new = {"x": x, **self.cfg}
        return self._actual_f_1(**new)
```

```
o = Obj()
o.f_1(1)
```

which prints

```
101
```

OR using the overriding approach:

```
o = Obj({"x": 100})
o.f_1(1)
```

which now gives

```
200
```

The defined class Obj looks pretty clumsy. Especially if several methods of the class should use the described logic.

How can I generalize the logic of `f_1` which basically *only* alters the parameters before calling the *actual* method?

Comment: What do you mean by "scalable"?

Comment: @chepner Revised the last question & dropped 'scalable' - hope it becomes a bit clearer.

Comment: Why pass arbitrary keyword arguments to `_actual_f_1` is `x` is the only one you care about? `return self._actual_f_1(x=self.cfg.get('x', x))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__init_subclass__` in a base class to decorate all methods in a class, in a transparent way, to pick the fitting named parameters form a `.cfg` dict if they are not passed.

So, first let's think of the code for such a decorator - applying arguments can be rather complicated because among positional X named parameters with "positional only" and "named only" in the mix, the number of combinationx explode

Python's stdlib have a `signature` call which returns a Signature object with enough functionality to cover all corner cases. I use it, and just a common path - so that if the arguments you want to apply automatically are normal positional_or_keyword or keyword_only parameters, it should work:

```
from functools import wraps

def extender(method):
    sig = inspect.signature(method)
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind_partial(*args, **kwargs)
        for parameter in sig.parameters.keys():
            if parameter not in bound.arguments and parameter in getattr(self, "cfg", {}):
                kwargs[parameter] = self.cfg[parameter]
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Here we can see that working:

```
In [78]: class A:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.cfg={"b": 5}
    ...:     @extender
    ...:     def a(self, a, b, c=10):
    ...:         print( a, b, c)
    ...: 

In [79]: a = A()

In [80]: a.a(1)
1 5 10

In [81]: a.a(1, c=2)
1 5 2

In [82]: a.a(1, c=2, b=3)
1 3 2
```

With only this decorator, your code could be rewritten as:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, cfg=None):
        self.cfg = cfg if cfg is not None else {"extra": 10}

    @extender    
    def f_1(self, x, extra):
        return x+100
```

And if you want a base-class that will transparently wrap all methods in all subclasses with the `extender`, you can use this:

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, value in cls.__dict__.items():
            if callable(value):
                setattr(cls, name, extender(value))
```

And now one can use simply:

```
In [84]: class B(Base):
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.cfg = {"c": 10} 
    ...:     def b(self, a, c):
    ...:         print(a, c)
    ...: 

In [85]: B().b(1)
1 10
```

This decorator, unlike your example, takes care to just inject the arguments the function expects to receive, and not all of the keys from `self.cfg` in every function call.

If you want that behavior instead, you just have to take care to expand the `cfg` dict first and then updating it with the passed arguments, so that passed arguments will override default values in the cfg. The decorator code for that would be:

```
from functools import wraps

def extender_kw(method):
    sig = inspect.signature(method)
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bound = sig.bind_partial(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs = bound.arguments
        kwargs |= getattr(self, "cfg", {})
        return method(self, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was already pretty helpful.
Though please review one thing, shouldn't the `sig.bind_partial` call take `self` as well?
So that it says: `bound = sig.bind_partial(self, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: yes - if all occurrences of "self" are omitted in the code above, it will simply be bundled into the `*args`, and it should just work - then the decorator would work for plain functions and not just methods as well. 
However, if the method uses "/" and "self" is a positional only argument, then it will break. (This code does not support positional only arguments, anyway)

Comment: btw, upon further working on this topic I stumbled across the python package [Gin Config](https://github.com/google/gin-config/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md).

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting "generalize" as "write this with fewer lines of code."

You wrote

```
        self.cfg = {}
        if cfg:
            self.cfg = cfg
        return
```

The 4th line is superfluous and can be elided.

The first 3 lines could be a simple assignment of `... = cfg or {}`

Or we could inherit from a utility class,
and make a `super().__init__` call.

---

So now we're presumably down to DRYing up and condensing these two lines:

```
        new = {"x": x, **self.cfg}
        return self._actual_f_1(**new)
```

Maybe write them as

```
        return self._actual_f_1(self.args())
```

where the parent
[abstract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)
class offers an `args` helper that knows about `self.cfg`.

It would [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)
the stack to find the caller's arg signature,
and merge it with `cfg`.

Alternatively you could phrase it as

```
        return self.call(self._actual_f_1)
```

though that seems less convenient.

---

Do [let us know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)
the details of how you wind up resolving this.